# Need a equivalent solution for CDBL in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have a MAccess function: **CDBL(DATE()) - DT_ENT** and I need an equivalent function for this in DB2. I have tried with CAST and VARCHAR_FORMAT
but those functions are not helping me.

Can you please help?

Thanks !

Comment: Please explain what the MS Access expression does, and why the DB2 functions you'd tried did not help.

Comment: Maybe DAYS function will  help you. Ex;  db2 "select days (current date) - days (date('2015-07-19')) from sysibm.sysdummy1"